# Microsoft Edge V18363 freezes immediately after opening in a C# Selenium project

Tags: selenium, microsoft-edge

I am trying to run MS Edge using the Microsoft webdriver with Selenium. The browser starts and get stuck before opening the URL.

I have created a C# MSTest Project and added `Selenium.Microsoft.Webdriver`.
Afterwards, I installed `Selenium.WebDriver.MicrosoftDriver`.

When I now run the test, Edge starts and get stuck immediately.

The error is:

> An exception with a null response was thrown sending an HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL http://localhost:49681/session. The status of the exception was ReceiveFailure, and the message was: Die zugrunde liegende Verbindung wurde geschlossen: Unbekannter Fehler beim Empfangen.

I also tried using `Selenium.Microsoft.Webdriver2` and installing the Microsoft driver using DISM.exe /Online /Add-Capability /CapabilityName:Microsoft.WebDriver~~~~0.0.1.0

Windows 10 and Edge are v18363. The zoom is at 100%

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the C# code you are using to start the driver?

Comment: did you set “Developer mode”?  Also see this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59234658/c-sharp-visual-studio-selenium-for-edge-os-version18362

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed the Microsoft WebDriver in an **elevated command prompt**? You should run the cmd **as Administrator** when you using `DISM.exe /Online /Add-Capability /CapabilityName:Microsoft.WebDriver~~~~0.0.1.0`.

Besides I installed the following NuGet Packages in my project:

[image]

Then run the following code to start a test:

```
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Edge;

namespace ecwebdriver
{
    public class webdriver
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {        
            var driver = new EdgeDriver();
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.bing.com/");

            var element = driver.FindElementById("sb_form_q");
            element.SendKeys("webdriver");
            element.SendKeys(Keys.Enter);

            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
            driver.Quit();
        }
    }
}
```